# the reducer is not performed

Tags: reactjs, redux

I just tried make simply reducer in react redux but it never called. After a lot trial i have no idea why it's not working. console.log in action is showing but reducer never is called.

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "store/actions";

function Login(props) {

const login = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
props.login();
};

return (
  <form onSubmit={login}>
    <button> login </button> 
  </form>
);
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
   login: () => dispatch(actions.login),
  };
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

actions file- i'm here console.log is showing correctly

```
import * as actionsTypes from "./actionTypes";

export const logout = () => {
return {
  type: actionsTypes.AUTH_LOGOUT,
 };
};
export const login = () => {
 console.log("i'm here")
 return {
  type: actionsTypes.AUTH_LOGIN,
 };
};
```

reducer

```
import * as actionTypes from "../actions/actionTypes";

const initialState = {
  isLogged: false,
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
  case actionTypes.AUTH_LOGIN:
    return {
     ...state,
     isLogged: true,
  };
case actionTypes.AUTH_LOGOUT:
  return {
    ...state,
    isLogged: false,
  };
default:
  return state;
 }
};

export default reducer;
```

many thanks for help

Comment: Did you wrap your app in a react-redux `<Provider>` ?

Comment: yes i did that  in app.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you forget to make a configuration of the store itself? :)

Something like that:

```
// at configureStore.js

import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from '../path/to/your/root/reducer'; // assuming that you use combineReducer function to gather all reducers in one place 

export default createStore(reducer);
```

Then in your app root you need to wrap entry component with the store provider:

```
import store from './store/configureStore';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

export default () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppRootComponent />
  </Provider>
);
```

> `AppRootComponent` -> your initial app component

---

For reference - [how to configure store](https://redux.js.org/recipes/configuring-your-store#creating-the-store)

---

**UPD**:
Looks like you were trying to pass the action creator to the `dispatch` function, instead of invoking it actually. Just make a call of that creator in the `dispatch`:

```
login: () => dispatch(actions.login()),
```

> BTW, here is the [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-feynman-59u5w?file=/src/components/Home.jsx) of your case

Comment: @robert it would be really helpful if you share what you have implemented so far over the codesandbox

Comment: i can't exactly do that, but this is how app.js file looks like: https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-surf-5cl5r?file=/src/App.js